# Using iPhone as mic for Mac, clicked "Disconnect", and can't find iPhone in "Sound Input" anymore. What should I do to fix?

Tags: iphone, audio, microphone

I have been using my iPhone as a Mic for my mac for a while. It works perfectly.

However, today I clicked the "disconnect" button and I can't see my iPhone in the Sound Input any more. What can I do to get it back?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: it worked. thanks

Comment: Write up an answer and I’ll up vote!  Be sure to ping me in comments so I am alerted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried rebooting my MacBook Pro. It doesn't work.

Then I tried rebooting my iPhone. It works.